# interactive terminal with winsock

Tags: c++, winsock, createprocess

I want to Create a terminal which can connect different computer by IP address in windows.
I use [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) because [_popen cannot use](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/-popen-will-crash-the-application-if-command-is-to/1226977).

file main.cpp

```
#undef UNICODE
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <ctime>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 2048
#define DEFAULT_PORT "7999"
static void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);
    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
static const char header[] = "\
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\
Server: Windows VC++\r\n\
Content-Type: text/html; charset=big-5\r\n\
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n\
\r\n";

static int running = true;
void callback(int) {
    running = false;
    puts("closing");
}
static HANDLE 
        g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL,
        g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL,
        g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL,
        g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;
#undef TEXT
#define TEXT(a) ((PTSTR)(L##a))

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = {};
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe"));
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation"));
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe"));
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation"));
    {
        PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo = {};
        STARTUPINFO siStartInfo = {};
        siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
        siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
        siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
        siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
        siStartInfo.dwFlags |=  STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        char szCmdline[] = "cmd"; // powershell
        if (!CreateProcessA( NULL, szCmdline,
NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo)) {
            ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
        }
    }
    signal(SIGINT, callback);
    assert(SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8));
    WSADATA wsaData = {};
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints = {};
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        ErrorExit(TEXT("WSAStartup"));
    }
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    if (getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result) != 0) {
        WSACleanup();
        ErrorExit(TEXT("getaddrinfo"));
    }
    SOCKET ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        ErrorExit(TEXT("socket"));
    }
    if (bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        ErrorExit(TEXT("bind"));
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    if (listen(ListenSocket, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        ErrorExit(TEXT("listen"));
    }
    puts("Server ready at http://localhost:" DEFAULT_PORT " [running]");
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = {};
    while (running) {
         SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
         if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
             printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
             closesocket(ListenSocket);
             WSACleanup();
             ErrorExit(TEXT("accept"));
         }
         {
            struct sockaddr_in  sockaddr;
            int namelen = sizeof(sockaddr);
            if (!getpeername(ClientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr, &namelen))
            {
                time_t timmer = time(NULL);
                printf("%s\t#%s",  inet_ntoa((in_addr)(*(in_addr*)&sockaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr)), ctime(&timmer));
            }
         }
        ZeroMemory(recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
        intptr_t recvlen =  recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
        if (recvlen == -1) {
            fputs("recv error\n", stderr);
            goto SH;
        }
        // fwrite(recvbuf, iResult, 1, stdout);
        if (recvbuf[0] == 'G' && recvbuf[1] == 'E' && recvbuf[2] == 'T') { // HTTP GET method
            send(ClientSocket, header, sizeof(header) - 1, 0);
            DWORD dwRead;
            // success on here
            if (ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, &dwRead, NULL)) {
                send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, (int)dwRead, 0);
            }
        }
        else {
            send(ClientSocket, header, sizeof(header) - 1, 0); // HTTP POST method
            char *ptr = strstr(recvbuf, "\r\n\r\n");
            if (ptr == NULL || ptr[0] == '\0' || ptr[1] == '\0'||ptr[2]=='\0'|| ptr[3] == '\0'|| ptr[4] == '\0') {
                fputs("parse error: POST request\n", stderr);
                goto SH;
            }
            ptr += 4;
            {
                DWORD dwRead=0, dwWritten=0;
                BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
                bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, ptr, (DWORD)((recvlen+recvbuf)-ptr), &dwWritten, NULL);
                if (!bSuccess) goto SH;
                printf("wrote %lu\n", dwWritten);
                // always block on ReadFile
                bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, &dwRead, NULL);
                printf("read %lu\n", dwRead);
                if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) goto SH;
                send(ClientSocket, ptr, dwRead, 0);
            }
        }
        SH:
        if (shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_BOTH) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            puts("shutdown failed");
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            ErrorExit(TEXT("shutdown"));
        }
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
    }
    puts("Exit Server [close]");
    WSACleanup();
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr);
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd);
    return 0;
}
```

file index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="big-5">
    <title>terminal</title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    input {
        min-width: 900px;
        color: green;
        border-width: 0px;
    }
    span, input, nav {
        font-family: Consolas;
        font-style: oblique;
    }
    font{
        font-size: 15px;
        color: cornflowerblue;
        font-family: monospace;
    }
</style>
<nav id='version'>waiting for server</nav>
<pre id='shell'>
<input id="new" value="print('Silav gerokê')">
</pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _history = [];
    var _index = 0;
    var shell=document.getElementById('shell');
    window.onload=function(){
        var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:7999", true);
        x.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('version').innerText=x.response;
                document.getElementById('new').focus();
            }
        }
        x.send(null);
    }
    shell.addEventListener('keydown', function(_){
        if(_.keyCode === 13){
            _.preventDefault();
            var old = document.getElementById('new');
            var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
            x.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:7999", true);
            _history.push(old.value);
            _index += 1;
            x.send(old.value);
            x.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
                    old.removeAttribute('id');
                    shell.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                    var ne = document.createElement('font');
                    ne.innerText=x.response;
                    shell.appendChild(ne);
                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.setAttribute('id', 'new');
                    shell.appendChild(input);
                    input.focus();
                }
            }
        }else if (_.keyCode==38) {
            if (_index){
                _index -=1 ;
                document.getElementById('new').value=_history[_index];
            }
        }else if (_.keyCode==40) {
            if (_history[_index+1]!=undefined){
                _index+=1;
                document.getElementById('new').value=_history[_index];
            }
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the HTTP GET method works, but POST not.

when I use cmd, block on ReadFile

when I use powershell, server just returns what it reads

it looks like this

[image: the image looks like]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what this stuff  `signal(SIGINT, callback);` doing in windows?

Comment: If the user press Ctrl-C (terminate process),callback will be called

Comment: so you're  dragging unix stuff into.

Answer (score 0):

Most Web Terminal use WebSocket for Duplex connection, e.g. Jupyter, WebSSH...

I use IO completion port(IOCP) for reading from child process's pipe, sending text to client, both of them are overlapped operation.

In my question, the pipe was created by `CreatePipe`, which is synchronous.In my answer, I use *named pipe* for asynchronous reading.So we don't have to waiting synchronously.

*main.cpp*

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <mstcpip.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include "Mine.h"
#include "llhttp.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32")
#pragma comment(lib, "Mswsock") 
#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet")

HANDLE heap, iocp;

#define assert(x) {if (!(x)){printf("error in %s.%d: %s, err=%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, #x, WSAGetLastError());}}

#include "types.h"
#include "pipe.cpp"
#include "handshake.cpp"

VOID CloseClient(IOCP* ctx) {
    if (ctx->client) {
        shutdown(ctx->client, SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(ctx->client);
        ctx->client = NULL;
        ctx->state = State::AfterClose;
#define USEMALLOC 1
#ifdef USEMALLOC
        free(ctx);
#else
        HeapFree(heap, 0, ctx);
#endif
    }
    _ASSERT(_CrtCheckMemory());
}
IOCP* initSocket(SOCKET client) {
#ifdef USEMALLOC
    IOCP* ctx = (IOCP*)malloc(sizeof(IOCP));
    if (ctx == NULL)
        return NULL;
    ZeroMemory(ctx, sizeof(*ctx));
#else
    IOCP* ctx = (IOCP*)HeapAlloc(heap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(IOCP));
    if (ctx == NULL)
        return NULL;
#endif
    ctx->client = client;
    HANDLE ret = CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)client, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)ctx, 0);
    assert(ret);
    _ASSERT(_CrtCheckMemory());
    return ctx;
}

#include "frame.cpp"

int http_on_header_field(llhttp_t* parser, const char* at, size_t length) {
    Parse_Data* p = (Parse_Data*)parser;
    p->length = length;
    p->at = at;
    return 0;
}
int http_on_header_value(llhttp_t* parser, const char* at, size_t length) {
    Parse_Data* p = (Parse_Data*)parser;
    p->headers[std::string(p->at, p->length)] = std::string(at, length);
    return 0;
}
int http_on_url(llhttp_t* parser, const char* at, size_t length) {
    Parse_Data* p = (Parse_Data*)parser;
    std::string tmp{ at, length };
    DWORD escaped = 1;
    char dummy;
    HRESULT res = UrlUnescapeA((PSTR)tmp.data(), &dummy, &escaped, 0);
    p->uri = (CHAR*)HeapAlloc(heap, 0, escaped + 1);
    assert(p->uri);
    *(CHAR*)&p->uri[escaped] = '\0';
    p->uriLen = escaped;
    res = UrlUnescapeA(tmp.data(), (PSTR)p->uri, &escaped, 0);
    assert(res == S_OK);
    return 0;
}
LPCWSTR encodePath(IOCP* ctx, Parse_Data &parse_data) {
    int res = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, parse_data.uri, (int)parse_data.uriLen, (LPWSTR)ctx->buf, sizeof(ctx->buf) / 2);
    ctx->state = State::ReadStaticFile;
    LPCWSTR file = (LPWSTR)ctx->buf;
    if (parse_data.uriLen == 2 && *parse_data.uri == '/') {
        file = L"index.html";
    }
    else {
        file += 1;
    }
    return file;
}
void processRequest(Parse_Data& parse_data, IOCP* ctx, enum llhttp_errno err) {
    WSABUF* errBuf = &HTTP_ERR_RESPONCE::internal_server_error;
    switch (parse_data.parser.method) {
    case llhttp_method::HTTP_GET: {
        switch (err) {
        case HPE_OK:
        {
            if (ctx->firstCon) {
                ctx->firstCon = false;
                auto connection = parse_data.headers.find("Connection");
                if (connection != parse_data.headers.end()) {
                    if (connection->second == "keep-alive" || connection->second == "Keep-Alive") {
                        ctx->keepalive = true;
                        DWORD yes = TRUE;
                        int success = setsockopt(ctx->client, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char*)&yes, sizeof(yes));
                        assert(success == 0);
                        puts("set tcp keep alive(SO_KEEPALIVE)");
                        auto keepalive = parse_data.headers.find("Keep-Alive");
                        if (keepalive == parse_data.headers.end())
                            keepalive = parse_data.headers.find("keep-alive");
                        if (keepalive != parse_data.headers.end()) {
                            auto s = keepalive->second.data();
                            auto timeouts = StrStrA(s, "timeout");
                            if (timeouts) {
                                int timeout;
                                int res = sscanf_s(timeouts + 7, "=%d", &timeout);
                                if (res > 0) {
                                    printf("set TCP keep alive=%d\n", timeout);
                                    int yes = TRUE;
                                    res = setsockopt(ctx->client, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_KEEPIDLE, (char*)&yes, sizeof yes);
                                    assert(res == 0);
                                }
                                else {
                                    puts("Error: failed to parse keepalive seconds...");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("I got Connection: %s\n", connection->second.data());
                    }
                }
            }
            auto file = encodePath(ctx, parse_data);
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(file,
                GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                NULL);
            if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                errBuf = &HTTP_ERR_RESPONCE::not_found;
                goto BAD_REQUEST_AND_RELEASE;
            }
            HANDLE r = CreateIoCompletionPort(hFile, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)ctx, 0);
            assert(r);
            const char* mine = getType(file);
            ctx->hProcess = hFile;
            LARGE_INTEGER fsize{};
            BOOL bSuccess = GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &fsize);
            assert(bSuccess);
            int res = snprintf(ctx->buf, sizeof(ctx->buf),
                "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                "Content-Type: %s\r\n"
                "Content-Length: %lld\r\n"
                "Connection: %s\r\n\r\n", mine, fsize.QuadPart, ctx->keepalive ? "keep-alive" : "close");
            assert(res > 0);
            ctx->sendBuf->buf = ctx->buf;
            ctx->sendBuf->len = (ULONG)res;
            WSASend(ctx->client, ctx->sendBuf, 1, NULL, 0, &ctx->sendOL, NULL);
        }break;
        case HPE_PAUSED_UPGRADE:
        {
            auto upgrade = parse_data.headers.find("Upgrade");
            auto pro = parse_data.headers.find("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol");
            if (upgrade != parse_data.headers.end() && pro != parse_data.headers.end()) {
                if (upgrade->second == "websocket") {
                    auto ws_key = parse_data.headers.find("Sec-WebSocket-Key");
                    if (ws_key != parse_data.headers.end()) {
                        ctx->state = State::AfterHandShake;
                        ws_key->second += "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                        char buf[29];
                        BOOL ret = HashHanshake(ws_key->second.data(), (ULONG)ws_key->second.length(), buf);
                        assert(ret);
                        int len;
                        len = snprintf(ctx->buf, sizeof(ctx->buf),
                            "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                            "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n"
                            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                            "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: %s\r\n"
                            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: %s\r\n\r\n", pro->second.data(), buf);
                        assert(len > 0);

                        ctx->process_name = StrDupA(pro->second.data());
                        ctx->sendBuf[0].buf = ctx->buf;
                        ctx->sendBuf[0].len = (ULONG)len;
                        WSASend(ctx->client, ctx->sendBuf, 1, NULL, 0, &ctx->sendOL, NULL);
                    }
                    else {
                        errBuf = &HTTP_ERR_RESPONCE::bad_request;
                        goto BAD_REQUEST_AND_RELEASE;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    errBuf = &HTTP_ERR_RESPONCE::bad_request;
                    goto BAD_REQUEST_AND_RELEASE;
                }
            }
            else {
                errBuf = &HTTP_ERR_RESPONCE::bad_request;
                goto BAD_REQUEST_AND_RELEASE;
            }
        }break;
        DEFAULT_UNREACHABLE;
        }
    }break;
    case llhttp_method::HTTP_HEAD:
    {
        if (err == llhttp_errno::HPE_OK) {
            auto file = encodePath(ctx, parse_data);
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(file,
                GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                NULL);
            if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                constexpr const char* msg = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n";
                ctx->sendBuf[0].buf = (CHAR*)msg;
                ctx->sendBuf[0].len = cstrlen(msg);
                ctx->state = State::AfterSendHTML;
                WSASend(ctx->client, ctx->sendBuf, 1, NULL, 0, &ctx->sendOL, NULL);
                return;
            }
            FILETIME ftWrite;
            SYSTEMTIME stUTC;
            LARGE_INTEGER fsize;
            if (GetFileTime(hFile, NULL, NULL, &ftWrite)) {
                if (FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftWrite, &stUTC)) {
                    if (InternetTimeFromSystemTimeA(&stUTC, INTERNET_RFC1123_FORMAT, ctx->sErr.buf, sizeof(ctx->sErr.buf))) {
                        if (GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &fsize)) {
                            int len = snprintf(ctx->buf, sizeof(ctx->buf),
                                "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" // no "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n" now
                                "Last-Modified: %s\r\n"
                                "Conetnt-Length: %lld\r\n"
                                "\r\n", ctx->sErr.buf, fsize.QuadPart);
                            ctx->sendBuf[0].buf = ctx->buf;
                            ctx->sendBuf[0].len = len;
                            ctx->state = State::AfterSendHTML;
                            WSASend(ctx->client, ctx->sendBuf, 1, NULL, 0, &ctx->sendOL, NULL);
                            puts("sended");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            errBuf = &HTTP_ERR_RESPONCE::internal_server_error;
            goto BAD_REQUEST_AND_RELEASE;
        }
        else {
            goto BAD_REQUEST_AND_RELEASE;
        }
    }break;
    default:
    {
        errBuf = &HTTP_ERR_RESPONCE::method_not_allowed;
    BAD_REQUEST_AND_RELEASE:
        ctx->state = State::AfterSendHTML;
        WSASend(ctx->client, errBuf, 1, NULL, 0, &ctx->sendOL, NULL);
    }
    }
}
DWORD WINAPI WorkerThread(LPVOID WorkThreadContext) {
    DWORD dwbytes = 0;
    IOCP* ctx = NULL;
    OVERLAPPED* ol = NULL;
    for (;;) {
        _ASSERT(_CrtCheckMemory());
        BOOL ret = GetQueuedCompletionStatus((HANDLE)WorkThreadContext, &dwbytes, (PULONG_PTR)&ctx, &ol, INFINITE);
        if (ret == FALSE) {
            /*
            * GetLastError() retrun thread local error
            */
            if (ctx) {
                int err=GetLastError();
                switch (err) {
                case ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE:
                {
                    if (ctx->hProcess != NULL) {
                        *(PWORD)ctx->buf = htons(1000);
                        DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
                        const char* msg;
                        if (GetExitCodeProcess(ctx->hProcess, &dwExitCode)) {
                            msg = "process exit with code %u";
                        }
                        else {
                            msg = "process was exited(failed to get exit code)";
                            // ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE on GetExitCodeProcess
                        }
                        int n = snprintf(ctx->buf + 2, sizeof(ctx->buf) - 2, msg, dwExitCode);
                        assert(n > 0);
                        websocketWrite(ctx, ctx->buf, n + 2, &ctx->sendOL, ctx->sendBuf, Websocket::Opcode::Close);
                        CloseHandle(ctx->hProcess);
                        ctx->hProcess = NULL;
                    }
                }break;
                case ERROR_HANDLE_EOF:
                {
                    BOOL res = CloseHandle(ctx->hProcess);
                    assert(res);
                    if (ctx->keepalive)
                    {
                    
                        ctx->state = State::AfterRecv;
                        ctx->recvBuf[0].buf = ctx->buf;
                        ctx->recvBuf[0].len = sizeof(ctx->buf);
                        ctx->recvOL.Offset = ctx->recvOL.OffsetHigh = 0; // reset reading position
                        WSARecv(ctx->client, ctx->recvBuf, 1, NULL, &ctx->dwFlags, &ctx->recvOL, NULL);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        CloseClient(ctx);
                    }
                }break;
                default:
                    printf("undefined error(GetLastError=%d): I'm going to ignore it\n", err);
                }
                
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (ctx == NULL || ol==NULL) {
            assert(0);
            continue;
        }
        if (dwbytes == 0) {
            CloseClient(ctx);
            continue;
        }
        switch (ctx->state) {
            // Accept-Ranges: bytes
        case State::AfterRecv:
        {
            ctx->buf[dwbytes] = '\0';
            Parse_Data parse_data{};
            enum llhttp_errno err = llhttp_execute(&parse_data.parser, ctx->buf, dwbytes);
            if (err != HPE_OK && err != HPE_PAUSED_UPGRADE) {
                printf("llhttp_execute error: %s\n", llhttp_errno_name(err));
                CloseClient(ctx);
                continue;
            }
            if (parse_data.parser.http_major != 1 || parse_data.parser.http_minor != 1) {
                puts("expect HTTP/1.1");
                CloseClient(ctx);
                continue;
            }
            printf("%s [%s]\n", llhttp_method_name((llhttp_method)parse_data.parser.method), parse_data.uri);
            processRequest(parse_data, ctx, err);
        }break; // end case
        case State::AfterHandShake:
        {
            ctx->state = State::WebSocketConnecting;
            if (ctx->process_name == NULL) {
                CloseClient(ctx);
                continue;
            }
            int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, ctx->process_name, -1, NULL, 0) * 2;
            if (size <= 0) {
                assert(0);
                CloseClient(ctx);
                continue;
            }
            WCHAR* name = (WCHAR*)HeapAlloc(heap, 0, size+2);
            name[size] = L'\0';
            size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, ctx->process_name, -1, name, size / 2);
            LocalFree(ctx->process_name);
            if (size <= 0) {
                assert(0);
                CloseClient(ctx);
                continue;
            }
            printf("=== spawn process: %ws(%d) ===\n", name, size);
            BOOL res = CreateCGI(name, ctx);
            HeapFree(heap, 0, name);
            if (res == FALSE) {
                int n = snprintf(ctx->buf+2, sizeof(ctx->buf)-2, "Error: create process failed, GetLastError()=%d", GetLastError());
                *(PWORD)ctx->buf = htons(1000);
                assert(n > 0);
                websocketWrite(ctx, ctx->buf, n + 2, &ctx->sendOL, ctx->sendBuf, Websocket::Opcode::Close);
                continue;
            }
            ctx->recvBuf[0].buf = ctx->buf;
            ctx->recvBuf[0].len = 6;
            ctx->dwFlags = MSG_WAITALL;
            ctx->Reading6Bytes = true;
            WSARecv(ctx->client, ctx->recvBuf, 1, NULL, &ctx->dwFlags, &ctx->recvOL, NULL);
        }break;
        case State::ReadStaticFile:
        {
            (void)ReadFile(ctx->hProcess, ctx->buf, sizeof(ctx->buf), NULL, &ctx->recvOL);
            ctx->state = State::SendPartFile;
        }break;
        case State::SendPartFile:
        {
            ctx->recvOL.Offset += dwbytes;
            ctx->sendBuf->len = dwbytes;
            WSASend(ctx->client, ctx->sendBuf, 1, NULL, 0, &ctx->sendOL, NULL);
            ctx->state = State::ReadStaticFile;
        }break;
        case State::WebSocketConnecting: {
            if (ol == &ctx->recvOL) {
                if (ctx->Reading6Bytes) {
                    onRead6Complete(ctx);
                }
                else {
                    onRecvData(ctx);
                }
            }
            else if (ol == &ctx->sOut.ol) {
                websocketWrite(ctx, (CHAR*)ctx->sOut.buf, dwbytes, &ctx->sOut.sendOL, ctx->sOut.wsaBuf);
            }
            else if (ol == &ctx->sErr.ol) {
                websocketWrite(ctx, (CHAR*)ctx->sErr.buf, dwbytes, &ctx->sErr.sendOL, ctx->sErr.wsaBuf);
            }
            else if (ol == &ctx->sOut.sendOL) {
                (void)ReadFile(ctx->sOut.pipe, ctx->sOut.buf, sizeof(ctx->sOut.buf), NULL, &ctx->sOut.ol);
            }
            else if (ol == &ctx->sErr.sendOL) {
                (void)ReadFile(ctx->sErr.pipe, ctx->sErr.buf, sizeof(ctx->sErr.buf), NULL, &ctx->sErr.ol);
            }
            else if (ol == &ctx->sendOL) {
                CloseClient(ctx);
            }
        }break;
        case State::AfterSendHTML: {
            CloseClient(ctx);
        }break;
        case State::AfterClose:
        {
            assert(0);
        }break;
        default:
        {
            assert(0);
        }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    system("chcp 65001");
    {
        WSADATA wsaData{};
        int ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        assert(ret == 0);
    }
    iocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
    assert(iocp);
    heap = GetProcessHeap();
    BOOL ret = initHash();
    assert(ret);
    sockaddr_in ip4{ .sin_family = AF_INET, .sin_port = htons(80) };
    SOCKET server = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
    if (server == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return 1;
    if (bind(server, (struct sockaddr*)&ip4, sizeof(ip4)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        return 1;
    if (listen(server, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        return 1;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, WorkerThread, iocp, 0, 0);
    puts("server listening at http://localhost/ and ws://localhost/");
    for (;;) {
        sockaddr_in sIn{};
        int sInLen = sizeof(sIn);
        _ASSERT(_CrtCheckMemory());
        SOCKET client = WSAAccept(server, (sockaddr*)&sIn, &sInLen, NULL, NULL);
        IOCP* ctx = initSocket(client);
        assert(ctx);
        ctx->recvBuf[0].buf = ctx->buf;
        ctx->recvBuf[0].len = sizeof(ctx->buf);
        ctx->firstCon = true;
        WSARecv(client, ctx->recvBuf, 1, NULL, &ctx->dwFlags, &ctx->recvOL, NULL);
    }
    WSACleanup();
    closeHash();
    _ASSERT(_CrtCheckMemory());
}
```

*types.cpp*

```
namespace Websocket {
    using BIT = BYTE;
    enum Opcode : BYTE {
        Continuation = 0,
        Text = 0x1,
        Binary = 0x2,
        Close = 0x8,
        Ping = 0x9,
        Pong = 0xA
    };
}

template <ULONG N>
consteval ULONG cstrlen(const char(&)[N]) {
    return N - 1;
}
consteval ULONG cstrlen(const char* s) {
    ULONG res = 0;
    for (; *s; s++) {
        res++;
    }
    return res;
}
enum class State : unsigned __int8 {
    AfterRecv, ReadStaticFile, SendPartFile, AfterSendHTML, AfterHandShake, WebSocketConnecting, AfterClose
};
int http_on_header_field(llhttp_t* parser, const char* at, size_t length);
int http_on_header_value(llhttp_t* parser, const char* at, size_t length);
int http_on_url(llhttp_t* parser, const char* at, size_t length);

struct Parse_Data {
    Parse_Data() : headers{}, uri{}, at{}, length{}, uriLen{} {
        llhttp_settings_init(&settings);
        settings.on_url = http_on_url;
        settings.on_header_field = http_on_header_field;
        settings.on_header_value = http_on_header_value;
        llhttp_init(&parser, HTTP_REQUEST, &settings);
    };
    llhttp_t parser;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> headers;
    const CHAR* uri;
    ULONG uriLen;
    size_t length;
    const char* at;
    llhttp_settings_t settings;
};

struct Stdio {
    OVERLAPPED ol, sendOL;
    HANDLE pipe;
    CHAR buf[100];
    WSABUF wsaBuf[2];
};

struct IOCP {
    SOCKET client;
    State state;
    OVERLAPPED recvOL, sendOL;
    char buf[4096];
    DWORD dwFlags;
    WSABUF sendBuf[2], recvBuf[1];
    bool Reading6Bytes;
    unsigned __int64 payload_len;
    BYTE header[4];
    struct Stdio sIn, sOut, sErr;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    Websocket::Opcode op;
    char* process_name;
    bool keepalive, firstCon;
};

namespace HTTP_ERR_RESPONCE {
    static char sinternal_server_error[] = "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body><h1 align=\"center\">500 Internal Server Error</h1><hr><p style=\"text-align: center\">The server has some error...<p/></body></html>",
        snot_found[] =
        "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1 align=\"center\">404 Not Found</h1><hr><p style=\"text-align: center\">The Request File is not found in the server<p/></body></html>",

        smethod_not_allowed[] =
        "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n"
        "Allow: GET, HEAD\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>405 Method Not Allowed</title></head><body><h1 align=\"center\">405 Method Not Allowed</h1><hr><p style=\"text-align: center\">You can only use GET, HEAD request<p/></body></html>",
        sbad_request[] =
        "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head><body><h1 align=\"center\">400 Bad Request</h1><hr><p style=\"text-align: center\">Thes server can't process the request<br>Maybe you miss some header(s)<p/></body></html>";
    static WSABUF
        internal_server_error = {
            cstrlen(sinternal_server_error), sinternal_server_error
    },
        not_found = {
            cstrlen(snot_found), snot_found
    },
        method_not_allowed = {
        cstrlen(smethod_not_allowed), smethod_not_allowed
    },
        bad_request = {
        cstrlen(sbad_request), sbad_request
    };
}
```

*pipe.cpp*

```
HANDLE newPipe(WCHAR buf[50], DWORD dwOpenMode) {
    HANDLE ret = 0;
    static __int64 volatile c = 0;
    for (;;) {
        swprintf(buf, 50, L"\\\\?\\pipe\\child\\%lld-%lld", InterlockedIncrement64(&c), GetTickCount64());
        ret = CreateNamedPipeW(
            buf,
            dwOpenMode,
            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,
            1,
            4096,
            4096,
            5000,
            NULL);
        if (ret != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return ret;
        int err = GetLastError();
        if (err != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY && err != ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) {
            printf("CreateNamedPipeW: %d\n", err);
            return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }
}

BOOL CreateCGI(WCHAR* cmd, IOCP* ctx) {
    {
        STARTUPINFOW si{ .cb = sizeof(si), .dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES };
        {
            WCHAR buf[50];
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa{ .nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), .bInheritHandle = TRUE };
            ctx->sOut.pipe = newPipe(buf, PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
            if (ctx->sOut.pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                return FALSE; 
            }
            si.hStdOutput = CreateFileW(buf, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sa, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
            if (si.hStdOutput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            ctx->sErr.pipe = newPipe(buf, PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
            if (ctx->sErr.pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            si.hStdError = CreateFileW(buf, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sa, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
            if (si.hStdError == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            ctx->sIn.pipe = newPipe(buf, PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND);
            if (ctx->sIn.pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { return FALSE; }
            si.hStdInput = CreateFileW(buf, GENERIC_READ, 0, &sa, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
            if (si.hStdInput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                return FALSE; 
            }
        }
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
        if (CreateProcessW(
            NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pInfo)==FALSE){
            return FALSE;
        }
        CloseHandle(pInfo.hThread);
        ctx->hProcess = pInfo.hProcess;
        CloseHandle(si.hStdError);
        CloseHandle(si.hStdInput);
        CloseHandle(si.hStdOutput); 
    }
    HANDLE hRet;
    hRet = CreateIoCompletionPort(ctx->sOut.pipe, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)ctx, 0);
    if (hRet == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    hRet = CreateIoCompletionPort(ctx->sErr.pipe, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)ctx, 0);
    if (hRet == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    (void)ReadFile(ctx->sOut.pipe, ctx->sOut.buf, sizeof(ctx->sOut.buf), NULL, &ctx->sOut.ol);
    (void)ReadFile(ctx->sErr.pipe, ctx->sErr.buf, sizeof(ctx->sErr.buf), NULL, &ctx->sErr.ol);
    return TRUE;
}
```

*handshake.cpp*

```
#include <bcrypt.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "bcrypt.lib")

static BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm=NULL;
static PBYTE hashO = NULL;
static BCRYPT_HASH_HANDLE  hHash = NULL;

BOOL initHash(){
    DWORD hashLen, dummy;
    // we need hash many times
    if ((BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider( &hAlgorithm, BCRYPT_SHA1_ALGORITHM, NULL, BCRYPT_HASH_REUSABLE_FLAG)) < 0)
        return FALSE;

    if ((BCryptGetProperty(hAlgorithm, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, (PUCHAR)&hashLen, sizeof(hashLen), &dummy, 0)<0))    
        return FALSE;

    hashO = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(heap, 0, hashLen);
    if (NULL == hashO)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if ((BCryptCreateHash(
        hAlgorithm,
        &hHash,
        hashO,
        hashLen,
        NULL,
        0,
        0))<0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
void closeHash(){
    if (hAlgorithm)
    {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);
    }
    if (hHash)
    {
        BCryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    }
    if (hashO)
    {
        HeapFree(heap, 0, hashO);
    }
}
BOOL HashHanshake(void* key, ULONG length, char *buf/*29 bytes*/){
    BYTE   sha1_o[20]{};
    // SHA-1 20 bytes hash
    if ((BCryptHashData(hHash, (PUCHAR)key, length, 0)) < 0)
        return FALSE;
    if ((BCryptFinishHash(hHash, sha1_o, sizeof(sha1_o), 0)) < 0)
        return FALSE;
    DWORD size=29;
    // base64 encoding
    return CryptBinaryToStringA(sha1_o, sizeof(sha1_o), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64|CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF , buf, &size);
}
```

*frame.cpp*

```
void websocketWrite(IOCP* ctx,  const char* msg, ULONG length, OVERLAPPED* ol, WSABUF wsaBuf[2], Websocket::Opcode op = Websocket::Binary) {
    ULONG hsize = 2;
    ctx->header[0] = 0b10000000 | BYTE(op);
    if (length < 126){
        ctx->header[1] = (BYTE)length;
    }else if (length < 0b10000000000000000){
        hsize += 2;
        ctx->header[1] = 126;
        ctx->header[2] = (BYTE)(length >> 8);
        ctx->header[3] = (BYTE)length;
    }else{
        puts("error: data too long");
        return;
    }
    wsaBuf[0].buf = (char*)ctx->header;
    wsaBuf[0].len = hsize;
    wsaBuf[1].buf = (char*)msg; 
    wsaBuf[1].len = length;
    WSASend(ctx->client, wsaBuf, 2, NULL, 0, ol, NULL);
    _ASSERT(_CrtCheckMemory());
}

void onRecvData(IOCP* ctx) {
    PBYTE mask = (PBYTE)ctx->buf;
    PBYTE payload = mask + 4;
    for (unsigned __int64 i = 0; i < ctx->payload_len; ++i) {
        payload[i] = payload[i] ^ mask[i % 4];
    }
    {
        switch (ctx->op) {
        case Websocket::Text:
        case Websocket::Binary:
        {
            (void)WriteFile(ctx->sIn.pipe, payload, (DWORD)ctx->payload_len, NULL, &ctx->sIn.ol);
        }break;
        case Websocket::Close:
        {
            if (ctx->payload_len >= 2) {
                WORD code = ntohs(*(PWORD)payload);
                printf("Websocket: closed frame: (code: %u, reason: %.*s)\n", code, (int)(ctx->payload_len-2), payload+2);
                websocketWrite(ctx, (const char*)payload, (ULONG)ctx->payload_len, &ctx->sendOL, ctx->sendBuf, Websocket::Close);
            }
        }return;
        case Websocket::Ping:
        {
            websocketWrite(ctx, (const char*)payload, (ULONG)ctx->payload_len, &ctx->sIn.ol, ctx->sIn.wsaBuf, Websocket::Pong);
        }return;
        default: {
            CloseClient(ctx);
        }return;
        }
    }
    ctx->recvBuf[0].len = 6;
    ctx->dwFlags = MSG_WAITALL;
    ctx->recvBuf[0].buf = ctx->buf;
    WSARecv(ctx->client, ctx->recvBuf, 1, NULL, &ctx->dwFlags, &ctx->recvOL, NULL);
    ctx->Reading6Bytes = true;
}
void onRead6Complete(IOCP *ctx) {
    using namespace Websocket;
    PBYTE data = (PBYTE)ctx->buf;
    BIT FIN = data[0] & 0b10000000;
    if (!FIN) {
        puts("FIN MUST be 1");
        CloseClient(ctx);
        return;
    }
    ctx->op = Websocket::Opcode(data[0] & 0b00001111);
    if (data[0] & 0b01110000) {
        puts("RSV is not zero");
        CloseClient(ctx);
        return;
    }
    BIT hasmask = data[1] & 0b10000000;
    if (!hasmask) {
        puts("client MUST mask data");
        CloseClient(ctx);
        return;
    }
    ctx->payload_len = data[1] & 0b01111111;
    PBYTE precv;
    ULONG offset;
    switch (ctx->payload_len) {
    default:
        offset = 0;
        data[0] = data[2];
        data[1] = data[3];
        data[2] = data[4];
        data[3] = data[5];
        precv = data + 4;
        break;
    case 126:
        ctx->payload_len = ((WORD)(data[2]) << 8) | (WORD)(data[3]);
        offset = 2;
        data[0] = data[4];
        data[1] = data[5];
        precv = data + 2;
        break;
    case 127:
        offset = 8;
        ctx->payload_len = ntohll(*(unsigned __int64*)&data[2]);
        precv = data + 0;
        break;
    }
    if (ctx->payload_len == 0) {
        ctx->Reading6Bytes = true;
        return;
    }
    if (ctx->payload_len+6 > sizeof(ctx->buf)) {
        puts("Error: data too large!");
        CloseClient(ctx);
        return;
    }
    ctx->Reading6Bytes = false;
    ctx->recvBuf[0].len = (ULONG)ctx->payload_len + offset;
    ctx->recvBuf[0].buf = (char*)precv;
    ctx->dwFlags = MSG_WAITALL;
    WSARecv(ctx->client, ctx->recvBuf, 1, NULL, &ctx->dwFlags, &ctx->recvOL, NULL);
}
```

*Mine.cpp*

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::wstring, const char*> mineTypeData = {
{L"html", "text/html"},
{L"css", "text/css"},
// skip
};
#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
const char* getType(const WCHAR* name) {
    auto s = PathFindExtensionW(name);
    if (s == NULL) {
        return "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    }
    s++;
    auto r = mineTypeData.find(s);
    if (r == mineTypeData.end())
        return "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    return r->second;
}
```

*index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Terminal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/xterm@4.18.0/css/xterm.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xterm@4.18.0/lib/xterm.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xterm-addon-webgl@0.12.0-beta.15/lib/xterm-addon-webgl.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xterm-addon-fit@0.5.0/lib/xterm-addon-fit.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;width: 100%;">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*index.js*

```js
var terminal;
this.onerror = alert;
cmd = prompt("process name(e.g. wsl, bash, cmd, powershell)", "cmd");
if (!cmd) {
    throw "error: user refuse to enter process name";
}
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.host, cmd);
ws.onopen = () => {
    terminal.write('* * * connection established * * *\r\n');
};
terminal = new Terminal({
    fontFamily: "'Source Sans Pro', 'Lucida Console','Source Code Pro', 'monospace'",
    cursorBlink: true,
    scrollback: 1000,
    windowsMode: true,
    bellStyle: "sound",

});
terminal.open(document.body);
ws.onclose = e => {
    if (e.reason != '') {
        terminal.write("\r\n* * * connection closed * * *\r\n"+e.reason);
    }
    else {
        terminal.write('\r\n* * *connection closed...* * *\r\n' + e.code);
    }
};
ws.onerror = console.error;
ws.onmessage = (m) => {
    m.data.startsWith && terminal.write(m.data);
    m.data.text && m.data.text().then((t) => {
        terminal.write(t);
    });
};
var buf = String();
terminal.onData((e) => {
    switch (e) {
        case '\u0003':
            terminal.write('^C');
            terminal.write("\r\n");
            ws.send(e);
            break;
        case '\u0004':
            terminal.write('^D');
            terminal.write("\r\n");
            ws.send(e);
            break;
        case '\r':
            ws.send(buf + '\n');
            terminal.write("\r\n");
            buf = "";
            break;
        case '\u007F':
            if (terminal._core.buffer.x > 2) {
                terminal.write('\b \b');
                if (buf.length > 0) {
                    buf = buf.substr(0, buf.length - 1);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (e >= String.fromCharCode(0x20) && e <= String.fromCharCode(0x7E) || e >= '\u00a0') {
                buf += e;
                terminal.write(e);
            }
    }
});
const fitAddon = new FitAddon.FitAddon();
terminal.loadAddon(fitAddon);
fitAddon.fit();
terminal.focus();
```